# Good beginning CAML tutorials?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml

right now I'm trying to get CAML down pat in SharePoint, where is the best place to start for this?  The MSDN content doesn't impress me much as being somewhat cryptic, though the Wikipedia entry was rather good for starting out.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

EDIT: Everyone below has great links, but alas I can only pick one answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way for me to learn was to download a few query tools so I could play with the syntax against my dev server in real time. Here's two that I found to be pretty good.

http://www.codeplex.com/SPCamlViewer

http://www.u2u.be/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list) a decent introduction for using CAML to query lists. I second the above recommendation for U2U's query builder tool, it's fairly indispensable for writing queries quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I've also used [a2zdotnet](http://a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=90b)

Comment: Here's the correct link: http://a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=90 :-)